# authorize.net C# wrappers/library

Tags: c#, wrapper, authorize.net

Are there any good libraries or wrappers for [Authorize.net](http://www.authorize.net/)?  The code samples available from their site seem a little ... raw.  I'm looking for an easy to use, object oriented API that I can simply set some properties, and it takes care of all the plumbing code under the hood.

I've found a few random blog posts of people offering their code that they've written, but code offered in a blog post doesn't give a high degree of confidence generally that it's been well tested.  I mean, we'll consider these if we have to, but we'd prefer something that looks like it's gone through some sort of release/testing cycle ... even if it's just that it has been posted on codeplex or something.

Thanks! :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use [SharpAuthorize.com](http://SharpAuthorize.com) on a few eCommerce sites.  One of which makes around $10K / month...

```
MinimumCreditCard authNet = new MinimumCreditCard()
    .Login("testdrive")
    .Password("password")
    .TransType(TransType.AUTH_CAPTURE)
    .CardNum(_cardNumField.Text)
    .ExpDate(_cardExpField.Text)
    .CardCode(_cardCodeField.Text)
    .Amount(8.00);

if (authNet.Authorize())
{
    // Money in your pocket!
}
```

It is noted on the site, but you should use a transaction id instead of the username and password in real code.

Comment: This appears to be [long defunct](https://flippa.com/2630132-profitable-isv-c-developer-preferred).

Answer (score 5):

A little late answering, but perhaps this?

http://code.google.com/p/payment-processor/

Answer (score 2):

See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51094/payment-processors-what-do-i-need-to-know-if-i-want-to-accept-credit-cards-on-m/52640#52640), it should help you out.  In my answer, I point to a [blog post](http://www.west-wind.com/presentations/aspnetecommerce/aspnetecommerce.asp#GatewayImplementations) as a reference.  You may need to view the revisions to see my whole answer, though.  For some reason it is getting cut off for me.  Check out the Gateway Provider Implementations section of the blog post.  It should help you out and get you going on implementing your own code for talking to the Authorize.Net API.  I've used a similar implementation and it has worked well for me.