# online store and Payments gateway

Tags: php, payment, provider, gateway

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Payment Processors - What do I need to know if I want to accept credit cards on my website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51094/payment-processors-what-do-i-need-to-know-if-i-want-to-accept-credit-cards-on-m)

Hi.
I need to create an online store.
It will work like a marketplace where the registred users can add their products to the application and then other users can buy them.

Probably I will allow payments with paypal but also credit card.

Any advices on a Payment gateway / provider to use?.

Also I have some doubts about how the payments will be made. Each payment has to be done to the user who sell the product and not directly to me  so I would need to store their bank account info. But then how to I pass the destiny account to the gateway?

I also would like to keep the transaction history and maybe get a fee for each transaction made within my app.

Note: i am coding in php.

Comment: This should belong on webmasters. Imho.

Comment: Already answered here on stackoverflow.com - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/51094/payment-processors-what-do-i-need-to-know-if-i-want-to-accept-credit-cards-on-m

Answer (score 0):

As a programmer at PayJunction, I have a very biased answer: Sign up for a merchant account at PayJunction.com :)

Incidentally, if you store any kind of account information, you are in scope for PCI compliance. You should try to find a way to NOT store any such information. For recurring bills, we provide a token in our API that you can store. Nobody else can use this token, so storing it is outside scope. Important: you want to be outside PCI scope! I think Authorize.net (our big competitor owned by Visa) does something similar.

My coworker suggests looking at [our sample code](http://www.payjunction.com/trinity/support/main.action?search.knowledgeBaseCategory.kbcParentId=43). There is a PHP example, but I'd actually look for a shopping cart lib that uses multiple gateways. I've only made patches for Ruby (ActiveMerchant) and Perl (our sample) code that uses us, so I'm no help on PHP matters. The API is pretty simple to use directly, though.

Seriously, make every effort to be outside PCI compliance scope. PCI audits are a pain.