# Secure sensitive data (credit card) on RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, encryption, security

Which are the best practice to store a credit card and billing information from my clients on my RoR application?

Actually I'm working with ruby 1.9.2, Rails 3.2.3 and Im thinking to deploy my app in Heroku.

Any help will be appriciated!

Comment: Actually 1.9.2 is the version of Ruby (the language). Ruby On Rails is a framework and the most used versions currently are 3.x (I'm no RoR expert but I think it would be best if you check the right RoR version to get better help)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Best practice is never store users credit card and billing information in your application. This information will be stored by a payment processor you chose for your application. Payment processor, or payment gateway can be [Autorize.net](http://www.authorize.net/), [PayFlow Pro](https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_payflow-pro-overview-outside), [Stripe](http://stripe.com/) and many other. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51094/payment-processors-what-do-i-need-to-know-if-i-want-to-accept-credit-cards-on) to find out all about payments integration on your site.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, but if its mandatory by my client to store it locally, there's a best practice to encrypt that information?

Comment: To store this information you should follow Payment Card Industry rules. http://www.pcicomplianceguide.org/