# Canadian website payment processor recommendations?

Tags: payment

This question has been asked before ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2556/whats-the-best-online-payment-processing-solution)) but I have slightly different requirements. First, I'm in Canada so that rules out Google Checkout and probably a few others. I just need a basic service that provides "Buy Now" functionality, no shopping carts or anything like that. The site isn't super high volume, so I'd like to avoid any site with crazy monthly fees. I also need the ability to setup "discount codes" (or whatever you want to call them) for special promotions. The site must also have some sort of payment notification service (IPN). I am currently using PayPal, but their lack of discount codes is really starting to restrict what I can do.

What have you used, or what would you recommend I investigate further?

Comment: Might be helpful to edit question with Canada in the title. Its a great question as many small software houses have been kicked out of their yahoo stores etc. because they are Non-US companies.

Comment: I replaced the "international" tag with "canada" - hopefully this will help fellow Canadians find this in the future.

Comment: Did you ever end up getting anywhere on this?

Comment: I decided to just stick with PayPal for now, until I see more demand for an additional payment provider.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have used [Beanstream](https://www.beanstream.com) in Canada. They provide a hosted service, where you provide a link to a custom Beanstream page in your site; they do all the payment processing and deposit the funds in your bank account. You can edit the checkout page to make it match your site, and create shopping carts or provide charges on a case-by-case basis. I know you said you don't need a shopping cart, but it is only $10/month more.

They also provide a gateway API if you want to accept credit cards yourself, but I find the hosted service far more convenient.

Comment: This is very cool. If you can answer, how long have you or your organizaiton been with this solution?

Comment: I would be interested in knowing this as well. Have you been happy with their service?

Comment: It was for a contract for a small gift company about 2 years ago. No handling of credit card data is done by their site, it is all done by Beanstream. The site is still up and I have not heard any complaints from the owners.

Comment: We have been using Beanstream for several years and it has worked out very well.  I just personally coded a new site that accepts ad hoc and recurring credit card payments and I used their API and some simple PHP CURL requests to implement it.  Apart from some painful server hardening to pass their security checks, it was a great experience.

Answer (score 1):

I've had good luck with [eMetrix](http://www.emetrix.com/). Also I've heard good things about [Plimus](http://www.plimus.com/) too.

Answer (score 0):

Has anyone had any experience with [eSellerate](http://www.esellerate.net)?
Plimus looks good, although I've heard some horror stories from the customers point of view related to their phone verification.

Answer (score 0):

On [TeamMentor](http://teammentor.securityinnovation.com) we use [Payflow Pro](https://www.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_payflow-pro-overview-outside) and have had a good experience with it. The SDK is straightforward and easy to use especially if all you need is a quick "buy now" option. They support international processing, although no paypal processing outside of the US.

Answer (score 0):

I saw the usage of [Moneris](http://www.moneris.com/index.php?context=/products) at a client site.

Answer (score 0):

I have used the Payflow Pro and the Paypal Payments Pro.  I found them easy to use from an API standpoint, although Payflow's php API worked well, it required a recompile of php and that meant less ease for patching our servers.  After the server setup each was equally okay.  The biggest drawback to using the Paypal products was the customer support and set up.  Setup was a nightmare and the "salesman"/account rep that we dealt with was less than helpful.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe You should add some details about Your requirements:

- If sufficient, try bank transfers. They are not known or free in all countries and I do not know about Canada, but it is the best payment system in Europe: You just tell Your bank to transfer the money to the destination account.

  - Advantages:

    - Cannot be undone.
    - The customer has a proof of the payment.
    - Free of charge (most banks in Europe)
  - Disadvantage:

    - Cannot be undone ;)
    - The customer has to order his/her bank to transfer the money.
    - It takes up to three days before the money appears in Your account.
- Do You need "instant" payment?
- International payments?

Comment: I do need international payments, and instant payments are a huge plus (for use with the IPN)