# Online merchant account for Canadian website

Tags: payment-gateway, payment-processing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Canadian website payment processor recommendations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/226353/canadian-website-payment-processor-recommendations)

I planned to use google checkout for a website selling just a few items (under 10). As I went ahead with registering, it appears that it is not available in Canada.

Can someone recommend a suitable substitute that will accept CC payments without taking a huge cut? Ideally something turnkey but customizable on the front-end.

Comment: This is the web, especially with payment processing, can we NOT treat an answer from 2008 as being necessarily relevant 2 years later (2010) when this question was asked, or 4 years later (2012) when this question was closed? Things change, there's no reason to treat it as a duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it looks like there's no comparative solution for Canada. The options seem to be paypal, authorize.net, a traditional merchant gateway or a hosted solution.

Comment: Authorize.Net is just a payment gateway, not a merchant account provider.